# Issues with figures placement and images in HTML

Tags: html, css, format, figure

I'm having some issues with getting the right layout with images in figures. I'm trying to layout the images like in the first image, but I can't get the images close enough, and I can't figure out why. I'm very new to HTML and I'm using figures so I can use figcaption for the words underneath. I want it to look like the second image.

[image]
[image]

Eventually, I'm going to have to wrap text around it too, so tips for that would also be appreciated!
Thanks!

Here's the code chunk.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: ivory;
      font-family: helvetica;
      color: sienna;
      padding-left: 80px;
      width: 1000px
    }
    
    h2 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    img {
      padding: 6px;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: burlywood;
      text-align: middle;
    }
    
    table {
      font-size: 14px
    }
    
    caption {
      caption-side: bottom;
      padding-top: 4px
    }
    
    figure {
      display: inline-block
    }
  </style>
  <h2><b style="color:darkred;font-size: 28px"> Samuel Finley Breese Morse - artist, photographer, inventor - and more </b></h2>
</head>

<body>
  <figure style="width:300px;vertical-align:top">
    <img src="pic/John_Adams-SFBMorse.jpg" alt="Morse's Portrait of Adams" width="180px" style="margin:10px;vertical-align:top" />
    <figcaption style="margin-left:15px;">Morse's Portrait of Adams</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure style="width:400px">
    <img src="pic/800px-International_Morse_Code.png" alt="Morse code, with instructions" width="400px" style="margin-left:20px;float:right" />
    <figcaption style="margin-left:100px"> Morse code, with instructions</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure style="width:200px;vertical-align:top">
    <img src="pic/Morse_telegraph.jpg" alt="The device" width="150" style="margin-left:30px;float:middle" />
    <figcaption style="margin-left:50px"> The device</figcaption>
  </figure>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you give us a working example (minimal reproducible example)? This way we can help you better. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for the details. Working with screenshots isn't really preferred. :)

Comment: Got it! Still new, so thanks for the FAQ